# Chamar função a partir de um evento

Tags: javascript, html5

Tenho um link que é gerado via JavaScript.

```
<a href="#" onclick="excluir()">Excluir</a>
```

Tenho uma função no meu .js.

```
function excluir(){alert("oi");}
```

Ao apertar no link recebo esse erro:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: excluir is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse erro aparece porque a função `excluir` não está no escopo global.

Verifica o teu código e coloca essa declaração da função no escopo global. Ou seja fora de qualquer outra função que possa ter, `DOMcontentLoad`, `DOMready`, `onLoad`, etc...

Um exemplo dessa situação é

HTML

```
<a href="#" onclick="excluir()">Excluir</a>
```

JavaScript

```
window.onload = function(){
    function excluir(){alert("oi");}
}
```

Neste exemplo a função `excluir` está dentro da função anónima que é passada ao `onload` e isso faz com que não esteja acewssível no escopo global.

Podes corrigir isto mudando o código para:

```
function excluir(){alert("oi");} // aqui está no escopo global
window.onload = function(){
    // o código que precisa correr depois da página ter carregado
}
```

ou então podes adicionar o event handler via JavaScript e não `inline` no HTML. Nota que no exemplo em baixo o escopo global não é poluído com variáveis defenidas dentro da função `onload`.

```
window.onload = function(){
    function excluir(){alert("oi");}
    document.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', excluir);
}
```

Comment: Obrigado deu certo...