# Perguntas javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu estou com dificuldades em resolver estes exercícios,se pudessem ajudar...
Este é o código :

```html
<form name="myForm">
    <label>Radio station name
        <input type="text" name="name" />
    </label>
    <select name="music_type">
        <option value="rock" selected>Rock</option>
        <option value="pop">Pop</option>
        <option value="jazz">Jazz</option>
    </select>
    <button onclick="saveForm()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

E as perguntas são:

- Como escrever uma função Javascript que guarda os valores de input da `form` em *session storage*, quando o utilizador clica no botão `Submit`?
- O que devo alterar na função anterior, usando jQuery, para que quando o botão for clicado, o background da `form` seja alterado para a cor cinza?

Comment: form name="myForm"
 <label> Radio station name <input type="text"
 name="name"></label>
 select name="music_type"
 option value="rock" selected>Rock</option>
 <option value="pop">Pop</option>
 <option value="jazz">Jazz</option>
 </select>
 <button onclick="saveForm()">Submit</button>
</form>

Comment: Olá John, bemvindo ao Stackoverflow! Nós nõ vamos resolver o problema para tí. Ajudamos com gosto mas tens de ser mais específico em que parte do código tens dificuldades. Falta ainda algum código, podes [edit] a pergunta e juntar o resto, juntamente com explicação do que conseguiste fazer e onde não consegues mais.

Comment: é apenas isto que tenho de código,a minha dificuldade são em relação a essas questões não conseguindo realiza-las

Comment: @johnmiras, o que você já tentou fazer? Qual a sua dúvida em relação ao que você tentou fazer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não vou resolver o teu exercício, mas posso explicar no que precisas pensar para resolveres.

Quando tens uma `<form>` com um `button` (e repara que quando o `button` não tem o atributo `type=""` ele toma por defeito `type="submit"`), ao carregar no botão ele vai enviar os dados da form e atualizar à página.

Como tens `onclick="saveForm()"` isso vai fazer correr uma função chamada `saveForm` que tem de estar no escopo global. [Podes ler aqui sobre o que isso quer dizer.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/69173/129).

Dentro dessa função deves gravar para o `localStorage`. Há [muitas perguntas aqui no SOpt sobre localStorage](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=localStorage), para saberes mais se não fôr claro.

Tens de ter em conta que o `localStorage` guarda *strings*. Ou seja tens de serializar os dados antes de os inserir. Podes fazer isso com o `JSON.stringify(teusDados)`;

#### Como ir buscar os dados?

Os teus elementos têm um atributo `name` certo? então podes usar `var select = document.querySelector('[name="music_type"]');` no caso do select, e o mesmo para o `input`. Para guardar o seu valor basta depois fazer `var valorSelect = select.value;`.

#### Como montar os dados?

Podes fazer um objeto por exemplo assim:

```
var teusDados = {
    select: select.value,
    input: input.value
};
```

e depois usares isso no `JSON.stringify` como referí em cima.

Em relação à segunda pergunta acho que é avançada para os conhecimentos que tens hoje. Precisas saber o que é jQuery e como ele recebe argumentos e os transforma em objetos com métodos jQuery. Isso é muita coisa para referir aqui. Mas os passos que tens de fazer usam estes métodos:

```
$(botão) // tens de passar o elemento <button> para o jQuery, provavelmente vais queres usar um seletor CSS: 'button'
    .closest('form') // para selecionares o ancestral/pai mais próximo que seja uma <form>
    .css(attributo, valor)
```

A sintaxe do `.css()` é `(atributo, valor)`. Vais querer usar `background-color` e côr cinzenta aí.

Boa sorte!